# Error in cookie law info plugin for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I've got a problem with one of my plugins.

The log files said:

> PHP Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /mnt/web008/c1/24/57250724/htdocs/WordPress_01/wp-content/plugins/cookie-law-info/php/shortcodes.php on line 125

It looks like that there is an aray given but a string expected? I dont know how i can fix this.

```php
/** Returns HTML for a standard (green, medium sized) 'Accept' button */
function cookielawinfo_shortcode_accept_button( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'colour' => 'green'
    ), $atts ) );

    // Fixing button translate text bug
    // 18/05/2015 by RA
    $defaults = array(
        'button_1_text' => ''
    );
    $settings = wp_parse_args( cookielawinfo_get_admin_settings(), $defaults );

    /*This is line 125:*/ return '<a href="#" id="cookie_action_close_header" class="medium cli-plugin-button">' . stripslashes( $settings ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Because $setting is an array so stripslashes give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error itself is pretty self explanatory.

The function `stripslashes` expects its parameter to be a string. A quick look at the Wordpress documentation suggests that the return value of `wp_parse_args` is an array, meaning the `$settings` variable is an array not a string and therefore passing it as an argument in `stripslashes` causes your error.

You can use `stripslashes` on an array, however, it requires a little bit more work. Here's the example given in the PHP documentation.

```
<?php
function stripslashes_deep($value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ?
               array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
               stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

// Example
$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

// Output
print_r($array);
?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

**EDIT:** It's probably worth noting that `stripslashes_deep` will return an array. If this is not the desired output then wrap the call the stripslashes_deep function via the implode function to convert it to a string.

```
implode(stripslashes_deep($settings))
```